# Why was the question about a problem pinging a Windows system from Ubuntu off-topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, scope

What was causing the problem, presented in the question https://askubuntu.com/q/418957/44293, only came into light when the question was answered. Before that it was unknown and most probably would have remained opened.

So, how is it that a question's on-topicness gets decided by the answer?

Plus closing that question is stopping other solutions from coming in that could in fact provide a fix to the problem without getting into Windows.

Comment: Got a link to the question?

Comment: Oops. Question updated.

Answer (score -1):

That is one doggy question and actually there's a lot of information missing of the question to accurately pinpoint where the problem is. I would actually ask those questions where multiple OS's are involved in broader sites (like SU) unless I'm 200% sure the problem is Ubuntu.

As can be seen on the answer the solution is not Ubuntu but Windows. If we left your question opened it will be taking more and more answer trying *to fix Ubuntu* when Ubuntu is just fine. Is the correct course of action is this cases. The same applies to questions that were fine under certain policy but with the change of scope it no good anymore.